# How to change color of CCDrawNode component?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I created a CCDrawNode object component and want to change the
   color, y created the object initially with a gray color, but if i
   want to changue it the color remains the same.

I tried:

```
     CCDrawNode * node;
     [node setColor:colorORG]
     [node setColorRGBA:ColorORG]
```

This code causes no effect on the component's color Any advice on
   this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i use cocos2d 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under 3.2.1, CCDrawNode derives from CCNode , thus the .color and .colorRGBA properties are visible (from CCNode). However, the node itself is a container for some draw primitives, and it is to the primitives that you must specify the color.

for example, i just added this to one of my MapLayout classes :

```
static CCDrawNode *dg;
if (!dg) {
    dg = [CCDrawNode node];
    [dg setColorRGBA:[CCColor cyanColor]];   // < does nothing !!!
    [self addChild:dg];
    // the following 2 lines add primitives, the color must be specified on each
    [dg drawDot:ccp(0,0) radius:50 color:[CCColor blackColor]];  // color the dot
    [dg drawSegmentFrom:ccp(0,0) to:ccp(80,80) radius:10 color:[CCColor blueColor]]; // color the line segment

    dg.visible=YES;
    dg.opacity=1.f;
}
```

shown here :

[image]